# if I had enough money, I could buy a 20-room mansion

Tags: conditional-constructions, will-would, could-modal

In the morning, person A says:

1. if my leg **were** not injured, I would attend the party tonight.
2. if I **knew** his home address, I could go to his house to meet him tonight.
3. if I **had** enough money, I could buy a 20-room mansion.

Q) Do the condition clauses in (1), (2) and (3) necessarily refer to the present time (= in the morning), and **not** the future? I mean:

1a) if my leg **were** not injured ***right now***, I would attend the party *tonight*.

2a) if I **knew** his home address ***right now***, I could go to his house to meet him *tonight*.

3a) if I **had** enough money ***right now***, I could buy a 20-room mansion.

NOTE: The person's leg was injured, they did not know the home address and they did not have sufficient money when they uttered sentences (1), (2) and (3) in the morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second and third sentences are not specific: they could mean now or any time.

The first is much more likely to be read as meaning right now, because the condition is not the normal one. A sentence starting *If my leg were injured* could relate to any time, but because one's leg being injured is an unusual circumstance, your sentence can't easily have that reading

Comment: You mean the condition clauses in (2) and (3) could also refer to the future. Am I right?

Comment: _Now or any time_ includes the future.

Comment: Just one more question: Could this one refer to "now or anytime": *If my mother **were** not ill, I would attend the party tonight*? The condition seems to me to be *normal* here.

Comment: @Mr.X, you're saying that being ill is the normal state for a mother???

Comment: Ah, I see now! Thank you very much. So it doesn't matter whether you use "could" or "would" in the result clause, the expression "If someone **were**..." almost always refers to NOW. Am I right?

Comment: In this case, the difference between _would_ and _could_ is whether you are saying  that if the condition held, you would certainly do whatever it is, or that you would be able to (without committing yourself to say that that would be what you chose to do).